# How to toggle an int / _Bool in C

Tags: c, boolean, int, toggle

Suppose we have an `int` and want to toggle it between `0` and `1` in a boolean fashion. I thought of the following possibilities:

```
int value = 0; // May as well be 1

value = value == 0 ? 1 : 0;
value = (value + 1) % 2;
value = !value; // I was curious if that would do...
```

1. The third one seems to work. Why? Who decides that `!0` is `1`?
2. Is something wrong with any of these?
3. Are there other possibilities? e.g. bitwise operators?
4. Which offers the best performance?
5. Would all that be identical with `_Bool` (or `bool` from stdbool.h)? If not, what are the differences?

EDIT: Many great answers with lots of valuable information, thanks! Unfortunately, I can only accept one.

Comment: Who decides that `!0` is `1`? The language specification decides that. So you can rely on it.

Comment: Differences in performance with simple statements like this are impossible to generalise, it depends on too many variables, not least the compiler, and the differences will probably be trivial.  I suggest you concentrate on clarity instead - there are probably more important areas of your code where you should worry about performance.

Comment: You can toggle between any two numbers with `sum - value`, where sum is the sum of the two numbers. So in this case: `1 - value`.

Comment: @potrzebie For a signed type, this requires that the sum can be represented. `^` can also be used to the same effect.

Comment: a^1 gives the best performance in most architectures I can think of (and there are many) -- if _a_ is initialized correctly -- consult my answer for further analysis

Comment: Not directly related to your question but since you got answers to your question number 1 I just wanted to add that for the very reason explained in the other answers value=!!value; will set any value to 1. A nice little trick.

Comment: You can write `value = (value + 1) % 2;` in a more fancy way like this : `(++value) %= 2`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`value = !value;` expresses what you want to do directly, and it does exactly what you want to do by definition.

Use that expression.

From C99 6.5.3.3/5 "Unary arithmetic operators":

> The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of its
>   operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares
>   equal to 0. The result has type int. The expression !E is equivalent
>   to (0==E).

Comment: So simple as that.. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

> The third one seems to work. Why? Who decides that !0 is 1?

C Standard guarantees that `!0` is `1`.

> Are there other possibilities? e.g. bitwise operators?

Yes, you can use the exclusive OR operator:

`value ^= 1;`

By the way I prefer this to  `value = !value;` as relational and equality operators can result to branching and bitwise operators usually do not.

Answer (score 12):

```
value = 1 - value; // toggle from 0 to 1 ... or 1 to 0
                   // when you know initial value is either 0 or 1
```

Comment: I don't know why so little likes. I think this is a beautiful mathematical solution!

Answer (score 4):

1. the language was designed that way.
2. Use the 3rd one, the others are right but unnecessarly complicated and therefore hiding the intent.
3. `value = (value ^ 1) & 1;`
4. They're all the same after optimisation.
5. `_Bool` would have the same results. The only thing different with _Bool is that values are coerced to be either 1 or 0. Meaning that `bool x = 55;` will have the value `x == 1`

EDIT: Corrected the formula in 3 because of my brainfart. I let the comments so that people can see my blooper.

Comment: -2 is 11111111111111110 in binary. It is there to coerce the value to 1 or 0. A simple ^1 would toggle the last bit but let all the other bits as they were. `!33==0`   `33^1==32` `(33^1)&-2==0`. Edit: upps, brainfart. It's of cours &1 that should be applied.

Comment: Ah yeah, that makes sense when "invalid" input (values other than 0 and 1) are possible.

Answer (score 4):

There can be noticeable performance issues with the alternatives depending on the architecture:

- !a might need in some architectures comparison and branching, which can be expensive depending on the pattern of 'a'

  - on some architectures there is conditional move (which is branchless), but
    which may require still 3 instructions to complete (with dependencies)
- 1-a most likely needs two instructions in many architectures

  - counter example: ARM has reverse subtraction **RSB** %r0, %r0, #1
- 1^a can be implemented in many architecture with a single instruction
- a=(a+1) % 2 will be most likely optimized to a=(a+1)&1, which requires 2 instructions

But anyway the first rule of optimization is that don't optimize a non working code.
To replace !a with a^1, one has to be 100% certain that it produces always the expected value.

Answer (score 3):

`value = !value` seems the most reasonable one, but you can also use `value = 1 - value` or `value ^= 1`. But the last two would both break if `value` is not `0` or `1`. The first one would still work.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression `value = value == 0 ? 1 : 0;` will work exactly like `value = !value;`. You can use any of the two.

`!0` is always `1` and also `!(any non zero value)` is `0`

Answer (score 0):

Use bitwise NOT operator

var = ~var;

Comment: ***Why*** is that a good idea?

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 2 years ago"*. Perhaps somebody else can chime in?